# If $P\in H_\kappa$ and $\Vdash_P \tau\in H_\kappa$, then there is $\bar\tau\in H_\kappa$ with $\Vdash_P \tau=\bar\tau$

Tags: set-theory, forcing

In trying to prove the statement in the question (where $P$ is some notion of forcing and $\kappa$ a regular cardinal), I'm stuck in the following step:

Fix a $P$-name $\tau$ and $p\in P$. Put $A_p:=\{\sigma: (\sigma,p)\in\tau\}$. I'd like to produce a set $B_p\subset A_p$ with $|B_p|<\kappa$ and
$$\forall \sigma\in A_p \exists \pi\in B_p (p\Vdash \sigma=\pi)$$
As the poset has the $\kappa$-cc, I can find a $\lambda<\kappa$ and a name $\dot f$ with $\Vdash \dot f:\lambda\overset{\text{onto}}{\longrightarrow}\tau$. I also know that $p\Vdash \sigma\in\tau$ whenever $\sigma \in A_p$, so given any $\sigma\in \tau$ I can find an extension $q\le p$ and an ordinal $\alpha<\lambda$ with $q\Vdash \dot f(\alpha)=\sigma$. My problem is that I'd like $p$, rather than some extension, to force such a statement.

Comment: See fact 3.6 http://info.tuwien.ac.at/goldstern/papers/tools.pdf

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti Thanks for the comment. I had looked at that paper, but I wasn't sure how to get the sequence $\langle x_i:i\le \lambda\rangle$, the condition $x_i\subset \{x_j:j<i\}$ a bit mysterious.

Comment: I remember being confused by this too when we went through that proof in class. It's late in the evening and I don't have my notes, but the idea is to build $x$ "from the ground up", so I think you can do something like $x_0=\varnothing$ and to build $x_\eta$ you pick a rank minimal element of $\mathrm{trcl}(x)$ which is both a subset of $\{x_\xi\mid\xi<\eta\}$ and distinct from all the previous $x_\xi$. At some step smaller than $\kappa$ you will have the whole of $x$ (because $\kappa$ is regular). This might be somewhat wrong but something similar will work

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti Thanks again. I think the following also works: put $\delta=rk(x)$. For each $\alpha<\delta$, well order $A_\alpha:=\{y \in\text{trcl}(x): rk(y)=x\}$. Then glue the well orders so that each $A_\alpha$ happens later than $A_\beta$. Let $\lambda$ be the order type of this well ordering, and $x_\alpha$ the $\alpha^{\text{th}}$ member of this well ordering.

Comment: @Reveilark That also works, it's also clearer. We're saying pretty much the same thing in two different ways

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\tau$ is a set of ordinals, then by $\kappa$-cc, there is some $\alpha<\kappa$ such that $\Vdash\sup\tau < \check\alpha$. Now define $B_\xi=\{p\in P\mid p\Vdash\check\xi\in\tau\}$, then $\{B_\xi\mid\xi<\alpha\}\in H_\kappa$, and so $\overline\tau = \{(\check\xi,p)\mid p\in B_\xi\}\in H_\kappa$.

You can now either use the axiom of choice and the fact that $H_\kappa$ is closed under Mostowski collapses, to conclude the full result. Or you can do this now by recursion on the Kinna–Wagner rank of $\tau$.

That is, sets of ordinals have KW-rank $0$; and $A$ has KW-rank $\alpha$ if $\alpha=\sup\{\text{KW-rank}(a)+1\mid a\in A\}$. Using this idea, define "semi-canonical names" to replace $\check\xi$, and rinse-repeat by induction for $\alpha<\kappa$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you say a bit more on how what kind of collapsing you're doing?

Comment: Take a set $x$ in $H_\kappa$, then $y=\operatorname{tcl}(\{x\})\in H_\kappa$ as well. Fix a bijection between $y$ and some ordinal, that lets you code $\in\restriction y$ as a set of ordinals. That lets you obtain $x$ as the unique maximal node in this relation. This shows that you only need to care about sets of ordinals, as long as you have the axiom of choice.